# git log: summarize movement of directories containing lots of files

Tags: git, rename, git-log

I'm doing some directory-level reorganization in my repository.  The resulting commits show a lot of file-level renames, which obscures the fact that conceptually all I've done is one or two `git mv dir1/ dir2/` commands.

Is there a way to make `git log` summarize this sort of operation to show that, conceptually, an entire directory was moved?  I thought that `--dirstat` or `--summarize` would get me at least close, but they don't seem to do what I want.

(I understand that git's repository model does not track any information about directories, only files.  However, the same is true of file renames, yet it's able to derive information about file-level renames after the fact.)

Here's a simple example:

```
#setup
git init
mkdir dir1
for f in foo bar baz; do echo $f > dir1/$f; done
git add dir1
git commit -m 'dir1'

#do the directory move
git mv dir1 dir2
git commit -m 'rename dir1 to dir2'
```

At this point I'd like to see something like this:

```
$ git log -1 --what-options-go-here?
b0ba9c9 rename dir1 to dir2
0       0       {dir1 => dir2}/
```

Instead, I can only seem to produce things like this:

```
$ git log -1 --numstat --oneline
b0ba9c9 rename dir1 to dir2
0       0       {dir1 => dir2}/bar
0       0       {dir1 => dir2}/baz
0       0       {dir1 => dir2}/foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git dynamically computes the file renames (using a "similarity index", see diff `-M` option; also `-B` and `-C`).  If, given commits *`c1`* and *`c2`*, the path *`path1`* has disappeared from *`c1`* and *`path2`* has appeared in *`c2`*, that's a "rename candidate".  If the file contents of *`path2`* are sufficiently similar to those of *`path1`*, the file must have been renamed (and possibly modified as well, if `-M` is less than `100%`).

To decide that a rename was a "directory rename" you'd need to add code of the form:

- every file in `dir1` disappeared (including untracked and ignored files)
- no file appeared in `dir2` before (including untracked and ignored files)
- given the dynamically-detected renames, "enough" files with name `dir1` were renamed so that `dir1` became `dir2` in the path, while the rest of the name remained the same

to decide that `dir1` was renamed to `dir2`. (The "enough" in the last point allows a few files to have been renamed outside of the new `dir2`.)

The really sticky point here is the two parenthentical bits, "including untracked and ignored files".  Clearly git can't tell you about the history of such files.  (One could of course just assume that no such files exist, perhaps under control of an option flag.)  I'm not sure if this was a factor in deciding not to write that bit of algorithm; but as far as I know, it's not in there.

Comment: Untracked and ignored files are by definition not part of the history, so it seems obvious to me that they would not be taken into account by any variant of the `log` command, including this directory-move-detection.

Comment: Remember that `git diff` output is fed into various patch applications (including `git apply` and `git am`).  If the diff output says "rename this file" and you rename all the files in a directory, it "just works" (except for leaving behind an empty directory) -- but if you get a "rename this dir" command and you rename a dir that contains untracked/ignored files, that's arguably wrong behavior.  I don't think there's an actual right/wrong answer here, just a perennial source of argument. :-)